# Failed to load keystore type JKS with path due to Illegal character in opaque part at index

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat7, keystore

I have recently started using Tomcat instead of WebLogic. I have completed setting up Tomcat and can access my application successfully via the non-ssl url. However, I cannot access the application via the ssl url (via https). The Tomcat log has an error I couldn't really find an answer to, so I'm hoping to find some help here. Thanks for any help, and please let me know if I need to provide anything else to make this more clear.
-Sean
My server.xml is configured as follows:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:\disk01\keystores" keystorePass="myPassWord" />

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

The tomcat log is showing the following:

> SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path C:\disk01\keystores
>   due to Illegal character in opaque part at index 2:
>   C:\disk01\keystores java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal
>   character in opaque part at index 2: C:\disk01\keystores  at
>   java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source)   at java.net.URI.resolve(Unknown
>   Source) ..... Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal
>   character in opaque part at index 2: C:\disk01\keystores  at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URI.(Unknown Source)   ... 27 more
>
> Mar 23, 2016 5:05:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>   SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-bio-8443"] java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type
>   JKS with path C:\disk01\keystores due to Illegal character in opaque
>   part at index 2: C:\disk01\keystores  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:453)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:344)
>   ....

Comment: I'm just guessing, but try `keystoreFile="file:///C:/disk01/keystores"`.

Comment: @coladict - That is a good guess. It shows that the Index moved. So I'm thinking I have to escape the character somehow. Any suggestion on how best to do that? Here is the new error: SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path file///C:\disk01\keystores due to Illegal character in path at index 9: file///C:\disk01\keystores
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 9: file///C:\disk01\keystores
 at java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI.resolve(Unknown Source)

Comment: You have to use forward slashes `/` in this format, instead of the usual for Windows backslashes ` \ `.

Comment: @coladict - Doh! Thanks for that. The error is now resolved.

Comment: Ask @coladict to post his/her answer then accept it as correct answer

Comment: @coadict - please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: had a similar issue, where I forgot to put a value for keystoreFile and it is searching your ${home} by default

Answer (score 2):

One other cause for this is that the file cannot be located by the JKS engine. Missing or incorrect characters are a main cause. It is best to copy/paste the path to the file from Windows Explorer or from a command prompt to the server.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

#### Env -

OS : Window
Server : Tomcat 9
Java : 8u201 64bit

#### Tomcat Connector Setting -

```
<Connector port="8443"
    maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
    maxThreads="150"
    minSpareThreads="25"
    maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true"
    acceptCount="100"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    clientAuth="false"
    sslProtocol="TLS"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
    keyAlias="cifin" 
    keystorePass="changeit" 
    keystoreFile=<SOME_SETTING> />
```

#### keystoreFile values -

I was getting this error due to below settings in Tomcat's server.xml Connector -

```
keystoreFile="file:\\\%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

Then I have changed as below -

```
keystoreFile="file:\\\C:\apps\Java\8\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

But still getting the same error

Again, I have changed the setting to below, and it worked

```
keystoreFile="file:///C:/apps/Java/8/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
```

Note - Do not use `%JAVA_HOME%` in the location of `keystoreFile`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to specify the keystore file path in windows is in the following format (be aware of the forward slashes instead of the backslash):
file:///C:/certs/trust-store/keystores

When using it in the JAVA_OPTS, be aware, they will be set only as long as you are in the current terminal.

set JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=file:////C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.91/certs/trust-store/keystores

As @coladict is not posting an answer, I took the liberty of posting this, as it is really useful.